# HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment is false IIS EXPRESS vs2013

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

I Always used HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment with .net 4.5/iis express/vs2012/Win8.

After a clean install with Win8.1/vs2013, working with the same projects give me HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment always false.

I've found that I can edit the machine.config for force that value, but I don't understand why from a clean install, in a development env. it doesn't work. In my preview win8 i didn't edit the machine.config and it worked perfectly